# Core Location, iBeacon & Region Monitoring

Tags: ios, core-location, ibeacon

I am looking to make an App similar to that of the iOS reminders app. Where a user can essentially set reminders to go off when a user has entered or left a certain area.

I am new to iOS app development and have been doing some research into what might be needed but I am getting a bit confused and was wondering if someone could clarify a few things for me.

From my understanding:

- Core Location is used to get your current location details
- iBeacon is used to set your device as a Beacon for others to discover
- Region Monitoring is used to monitor for when you enter a specific region

Am I correct in my assumptions? If not could someone please correct me. Also am I looking at the right kits that will help me achieve this?

What I would like to do is have a table of saved records that are triggered individually when they enter or leave there specified locations. (Do I use Region Monitoring for this)

Also how would I make this app still run in the background, once it is closed, and still trigger events (like the iOS Reminders App).

I have found a few basic tutorials that help me get my current location with CoreLocation but does anyone know of any other tutorials that might help me out? Or know themselves how I can go about accomplishing this.

Would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best choice for your app is using Region Monitoring:

1. You could register up to 20 regions;
2. iOS will launch your app automatically if iPhone enters the observed region.

From [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html):

> If a region crossing occurs while your iOS app is not running, the
>   system **automatically wakes it up (or relaunches it) in the background**
>   so that it can process the event. When relaunched, all of the regions
>   you configured previously are made available in the monitoredRegions
>   property of any location manager objects you create.
>
> **An app can register up to 20 regions at a time.** In order to report
>   region changes in a timely manner, the region monitoring service
>   requires network connectivity.

Comment: Thank you very much @Visput I will look into Region Monitoring. This does sound like the best choice for my App. Thanks again!

Comment: Location regions and iBeacon regions are also shared. So you only get 20 total between the two.